# How do I ensure a field is defined in struct?

Tags: go, struct

This might be a bit silly and I apologize if it is but how do I guarantee that a field is defined in a struct before I can use it?

Let me explain this with example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type animal struct {
    name     string
    activity func()
}

var elephant = animal{
    name: "elephant",
    activity: func() {
        fmt.Println("Eat grass")
        fmt.Println("Stampede")
    },
}

var lemur = animal{
    name: "lemur",
    activity: func() {
        fmt.Println("Eat fruits")
        fmt.Println("Climb trees")
    },
}

func main() {
    zoo := []animal{
        elephant,
        lemur,
        // more goes here
    }

    for _, cage := range zoo {
        cage.activity()
    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0nXNk0DMuVd

Let's say there can be more `animal` structs in `zoo` array. Is there a better way to make sure that every animal must define `activity` function other than doing the following:

```
for _, cage := range zoo {
    if cage.activity != nil {
      cage.activity()
    }
}
```

Using `method` doesn't look feasible here as implementation of `activity` is quite different for each animal. I was also thinking of using `interface` but then wouldn't I have to create a type of every animal?
The reason I'm not happy with the above `if` solution is that the check is done in runtime only. However, if that's the only way to approach this problem then I'm okay with that too.

Comment: This seems like a good place to use an interface. Yes, you would have a separate type for each animal. If you want to keep your current implementation, you can write a test that ensures that `activity` is defined for each animal. (You then have to make sure to run the test, of course.) See https://golang.org/pkg/testing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to statically ensure that the function is set for each value is to use methods and an interface.  This requires a type for each kind of animal as you noted.

One approach to ensure that function is set a runtime is to use a factory function for creating animal values. This function can check that activity is not nil.

```
func newAnimal(name string, activity func()) animal {
   if activity == nil {
      panic("missing activity for " + name)
   }
   return animal{name, activity}
}

var elephant = newAnimal("elephant", func() {
    fmt.Println("Eat grass")
    fmt.Println("Stampede")
})

var lemur = newAnimal("lemur", func() {
    fmt.Println("Eat fruits")
    fmt.Println("Climb trees")
})
```

A variation is to build the zoo using function calls:

```
type zoo []animal

func addAnimal(name string, activity func()) {
   if activity == nil {
      panic("missing activity for " + name)
   }
   zoo = append(zoo, animal{name, activity})
}

func init() {
  addAnimal("elephant", func() {
    fmt.Println("Eat grass")
    fmt.Println("Stampede")
  })
  addAnimal("lemur", func() {
    fmt.Println("Eat fruits")
    fmt.Println("Climb trees")
  })
}
```

Comment: The second way isn't that bad actually even though it's can't be statically checked. Thank you for confirming my doubt.